# NAME ERROR : name 'datetime ' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

hey guys i have just started coding and was trying some new things but after looking at all the code lines i am still coming all with the error.

**code:**

```
import time

"""
This is a prastise session

"""
list=[]

for i in range(10):
    list.append(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(2)
```

**Error:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "importtime.py", line 11, in <module>
   list.append(datetime.datetime.now())
   NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

can anybody help?
thank you

Comment: Add `import datetime` to the top

Comment: use `import datetimep`

Comment: thx buddy , got it ryt

Answer (score 0):

You need to import datetime:

```
import datetime
import time
"""
This is a prastise session

"""
list=[]

for i in range(10):
    list.append(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(2)
```